# Actionbar convert tabs to list navigation if there is no room

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I have an actionbar with a logo, a title, 2 tabs and a search function.
On a phone (3.5") everything works fine.
The actionbar has 2 lines. The logo title and the search function appear on the first line and the tabs apear on the second line.
[image]

On my tablet (7") everyting is shown on a single line. But the tabs will be convert to a list when i click the search icon.
[image: tabs as list navigation]

How can i split the (sherlock)actionbar in 2 lines on my 7" tabblet?
Or is there an other way to solve this problem?

Comment: does it comes back to tabs when you close the search input?

Comment: Yes. When I style the tabs background, the background disapear when i expand the searchview. (so i'm sure it's an actionlist and no tabbar anymore)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution to separate the tabs in code.

```
private void embeddedTabs(Object actionBar, Boolean embed_tabs) {


try {

        if (actionBar instanceof ActionBarWrapper) {
            //ICS and forward
            try {
                Field actionBarField = actionBar.getClass().getDeclaredField("mActionBar");
                actionBarField.setAccessible(true);
                actionBar = actionBarField.get(actionBar);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("", "Error enabling embedded tabs", e);
        }
    }
    Method setHasEmbeddedTabsMethod = actionBar.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("setHasEmbeddedTabs", boolean.class);
    setHasEmbeddedTabsMethod.setAccessible(true);
    setHasEmbeddedTabsMethod.invoke(actionBar, embed_tabs);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("", "Error marking actionbar embedded", e);
}
```

}

But now I have a new problem. The tabs don't fill the tabbar completely.
[Actionbar tabs don't fill the tabbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13583885/actionbar-tabs-dont-fill-the-tabbar)

Answer (score 5):

In ActionBarSherlock, there is a boolean value(abs__action_bar_embed_tabs) that determine whether the Tabs should be embed in ActionBar, and this value is stored in two files.

- In values/abs__bools.xml. It is false.
- In values-w480/abs__bools.xml. It is true.

This means Tabs will be embed only if the width of device is bigger than 480dp.

If you want to control it all by yourself, you can just create values-w480 in your own project, and set abs__action_bar_embed_tabs to false to override the value in library project.

Comment: thanks. this explains such strange behaviour of action bar sherlock.

Comment: you mean ''values-w480dp'' folder name, according to https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/actionbarsherlock/res/values-w480dp/abs__bools.xml

Comment: anyway: no use according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13581155/how-does-action-bar-embed-tabs-exactly-work-in-android

Answer (score 1):

this method works fine for me:

JUST PUT THE NAVIGATION METHOD, AFTER ADDING ADDING TABS:

```
... // adding tabs
```

`bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.Navigation_mode_tabs);`