# Tabs on Main Section of ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

How can i archive a Tab layout like this in Android ? The Tab Navigation is part of that
Main ActionBar and is not below. PS: Im using ActionBar Sherlock

At the moment is just do:

```
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
```

[image: Current ActionBar]

But i want a look like this:

[image: ActionBar Design]

Thanks for help,
Kitesurfer

Comment: 1st is portrait mode and 2nd is landscape mode. It will automatically change your looks once you change your orientation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tab will be displayed in actions bar but only if action bar has space. When you are in landscape mode your tabs will move to action bar because in landscape mode action bar has more room.

Comment: Ok, was some kind of odd question from me. I've seen somewhere that APPs seem to force this in some way. I played with  android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" on a Galaxy Nexus and two tabs, but still cant force this. So the ActionBar seems to complete control this to me.

Comment: ehm... if you want to you can still have embedded tabs... see my answer.

Answer (score 4):

I don't recommend doing this but you could override the ActionBar and ABS styles:

```
<bool name="abs__action_bar_embed_tabs">false</bool> //for ActionBarSherlock
<bool name="action_bar_embed_tabs">false</bool> //for default ActionBar
```

Comment: I haven't been able to get this to work. I created a file in values called `bools.xml` in my own project, but that doesn't seem to have an affect. I also tried changing the value in the ABS library, but no joy there either. Running android 4.2.2.

Comment: For some reason this does not work in landscape mode. Are you using it in portrait?

Comment: It works fine for me in landscape mode (as it should by the library's default), I can't get it to work in portrait at all.

Comment: Thanks, this works for me. Anybody facing problem, make sure you set value in all ```values-*``` folder

Answer (score 0):

From [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/actionbarsherlock/hmmB1JqDeCk) thread. On the topic of overriding the Action Bar tab functionality.

> Jake Wharton
>
> I am obligated to tell you this is probably a Bad Idea™ and I don't recommend it. When you fight the platform you almost always end up losing.

I am inclined to agree about fighting the platform. Instead I opted to abandon the stock tab navigation (from both the android platform and ABS library) and instead wrote a layout that looks basically the same as the tabs, and used it as a custom view, applying it using [`ActionBar.setCustomView(View)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setCustomView%28android.view.View%29) and [`ActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setDisplayShowCustomEnabled%28boolean%29) methods.

This uses the ActionBar api in the standard way (ie. Not fighting the platform) and, as is pointed out in that thread, the tab view is simply a `LinearLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13581155/how-does-action-bar-embed-tabs-exactly-work-in-android). This implements a method that will let you select whether you want the tabs in a separate row or in the top row, regardless of screen orientation.

For those who are using this code with the native ActionBar, simply omit the `if (actionBar instanceof ActionBarWrapper)` and the block underneath it.

Bear in mind, though, that this is somewhat of a hack and might break in future Android versions.