# Stacked ActionBar tab bar not filling parent

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm creating Action Bar navigation tabs, but when the Action Bar is stacked the tabs are not getting the whole width space. I have a foto to illustrate it.

[image]

Is possible, in this case, giving to each tab 50% of the screen width?

Thank you

I'm editing to say that it's not a Sherlock Action Bar. And I'm working in a Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1 and in a Nexus 7. And now, testing it in the Nexus, I noticed that it's behaviour is different. Another screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Kaixo Jon, I am running into the same issue. Did you get to a conclusion?

Comment: Ez, sorry mdelolmo but I'm in the same situation. It's absurd.

Comment: Why not using Canvas for it? you can draw the tab item and then with fragment fill the space below

Comment: @PierGiorgioMisley That's probably not a good idea.

Comment: If not canvas i think also two textboxes works, you just have to use two textboxes and give them half space, than with textAlignment and a custom layout you can draw them as you wish :) and for botside best idea are fragments

Comment: @EricS. Are you working with `TabLayout` from design support library?

Comment: @Vikram Unfortunately that's not an option at my API level. (18 only, it's a weird project)

Comment: @EricS. Design support library is available for API level 7 & above: [Link](http://android-developers.blogspot.ca/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html). I still don't have an answer to your question, but I am willing to look if you can confirm your choice of tools.

Comment: @Vikram You're right, I was mistaken; I didnt know 18 could use the latest 2.2 v7 support library. If I can use TabLayout, this shouldn't be a problem because the tabs are no longer attached to the action bar. You're welcome to try to fix this problem anyway, but my bounty has just expired.

Comment: - Facing the same issue. :(

Comment: @Vikram API level 7 is required to run tablayout, but the specific Android Design Library has a compile time dependency of 22.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I don't think that's feasible at the moment. I've been trying to do the same thing for the past few days, and here's what I have found so far.

The Android framework uses a class called ActionBarPolicy to set some rules regarding the ActionBar's behavior. 
In this file (which can be found here : https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/com/android/internal/view/ActionBarPolicy.java), you'll find a method called getStackedTabMaxWidth() which returns a dimen value (currently set in the ressources at 160dip).

This value is used is the inner class TabView placed in ScrollingTabContainerView (https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/com/android/internal/widget/ScrollingTabContainerView.java). TabView is the private implementation of the ActionBar's TabBar.

Now I don't think this value nor this behavior can be modified, except maybe using Reflection. I don't know enough about it to do so, so if someone could manage such a thing, don't hesitate to say so, because this really is a bad behavior which doesn't look great on some tablets.

Comment: From https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/b8139af3dcae80c0030afd0354dc424a7c72c3d9 

"Stacked action bar tabs now have a width limit. This prevents
super-wide tabs that can span the whole screen. The cluster of tabs
is centered if it does not span the full width.
"

Comment: It looks like Android is moving away from attching tabs to the actionbar in Android M. Unfortunately the problem persists in older versions.

Answer (score 0):

Android stacked action bar tabs do not have adjustable widths.

> "Stacked action bar tabs now have a width limit. This prevents super-wide tabs that can span the whole screen. The cluster of tabs is centered if it does not span the full width. " https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/b8139af3dcae80c0030afd0354dc424a7c72c3d9

The solution is to use the **[TabLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html)** API from the Android Design Support Library released with Android 5.0. The Android Support library requires the appcompat library, but that dependency is resolved for you if you build using gradle.

For most developers, this will not be an issue, but the TabLayout setup requries at least SDK API level 22, because the appcompat dependency is compiled against 22. However, **TabLayout** does not have a runtime dependency on 22, meaning you can run it on devices up to API level 7.

tl;r - Use Tablayout from Android Design Library. Requires API level 22 on developer, but can run on older phones up to v7.