# Set width of tabs

Tags: android, tabs, width, tabbar

I found a lot of questions about this topic, but no working answers. So I have to ask the same question again...

[image: tabs]

I have a `Fragment` in which I am displaying two `Tabs`. On smartphone devices everything looks fine. Just like I want to. But on tablets (or generally on larger screens) the two `Tabs` are centered, that there are two "gaps", left an right of the `Tabs`. 
Now I want to get rid of these gaps. My favorite solution would be to stretch both `Tabs` to cover the complete screen width. If that is not possible, I at least want to change the color of the `TabBar`.

I create and add my tabs like this (I left out the text and TabListener creation and assignment):

```
Tab tabA;
Tab tabB;

final ActionBar myActionBar = ((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
myActionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

myActionBar.addTab(tabA);
myActionBar.addTab(tabB);
```

When I try something like this

```
myActionBar.getTabAt(0).getCustomView().getLayoutParams().width = 200;
```

I always have a NullPonterException. I also tried to use a CustomView for the tabs. I created a new TabWidget.xml Like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabWidget xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="250dip"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    >

</TabWidget>
```

But no chance. The tab size just does not change.

Answer (score 1):

Just found this post: [Stacked ActionBar tab bar not filling parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14979327/stacked-actionbar-tab-bar-not-filling-parent)

It seems as if it is not possible to change the `Tab` width to a value bigger 160 dip. So for the moment I have to use plan b and change the color of the `TabBar`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of tabs, try to place image view with background image

Comment: Sorry, but that is no solution for me. I want to use tabs. It must be possible to change the width!